# Split string into tokens in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I parse a string into tokens in PL/SQL?

For example, this is my string:

```
170823-14785
```

and the parsing I want is:

```
17
08
23
-1
47
85
```

Comment: `SUBSTR(i, 2)` where i = 1,3,5,7,9,... until `i >= LENGTH(str)` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm

Comment: What is the logic behind the split? All two characters long tokens? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you want replace all consecutive 2 chars, with following space symbol

If so, then something like this: (No PL/SQL needed for this)

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('170823-14785', '(.{2})', '\1 ') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to split a string into tokens of 2 characters each, no matter the content of the string, this can be a way, with no need for PL/SQL:

```
select substr(str, (level-1)*2 +1, 2)
from (
        select '170823-14785' str
        from dual
     )
connect by 2*level -1 <= length(str)
order by level
```

Which gives:

```
SUBSTR(S
--------
17
08
23
-1
47
85
```

Adding something to the select list will clarify how this works:

```
select substr(str, (level-1)*2 +1, 2) as token,
       level,
       (level-1)*2 +1 as startPos       
from (
        select '170823-14785' str
        from dual
     )
connect by 2*level -1 <= length(str)
order by level

TOKEN         LEVEL   STARTPOS
-------- ---------- ----------
17                1          1
08                2          3
23                3          5
-1                4          7
47                5          9
85                6         11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR( string, position, substring_length )`:

```
DECLARE
  v_input VARCHAR2(20) := '170823-14785';
  v_str1  CHAR(2);
  v_str2  CHAR(2);
  v_str3  CHAR(2);
  v_str4  CHAR(2);
  v_str5  CHAR(2);
  v_str6  CHAR(2);
BEGIN
  v_str1 := SUBSTR( v_input,  1, 2 );
  v_str2 := SUBSTR( v_input,  3, 2 );
  v_str3 := SUBSTR( v_input,  5, 2 );
  v_str4 := SUBSTR( v_input,  7, 2 );
  v_str5 := SUBSTR( v_input,  9, 2 );
  v_str6 := SUBSTR( v_input, 11, 2 );
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses REGEXP_SUBSTR() and handles an odd number of characters by making the second character optional and makes the group of 2 characters valid when followed by a character or the end of the string.  Always expect the unexpected!

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select '170823-147854' from dual
    )
    select level, regexp_substr(str, '((.)(.)?)(.|$)', (((level-1)*2)+1), 1, NULL, 1) parsed
    from tbl
    connect by level <= round(length(str)/2)
    order by level;

     LEVEL PARSED
---------- -------------
         1 17
         2 08
         3 23
         4 -1
         5 47
         6 85
         7 4

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```